# Help programming a simulation in stageros

Tags: simulation, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to program a simulation with stage, where I'd like a robot to move forward till he detects an obstacle, and then, turn until he can continue forward. For that I know I have to subscribe to scan topic and to publish to cmd_vel to make the robot move (thanks, Martin Günther!).
But I don't know how to interact with stage itself. I think I could manage to write the subscribe and publish algorithms with what I learnt from the publisher's and subscriber's tutorials, but once that is done, I'm at a loss as to how execute the simulation. I read some of [this link](http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/doc/Stage-2.0.0/group__stage.html), but I'm still really lost. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11532/help-programming-a-simulation-in-stageros./) by [jlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1132/jlo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 385 on 2011-10-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will need a so-called world file which contains a description of the virtual environment and the characteristics of your simulated robot. The stage package contains a suitable demo world file. You must start Stage with the world file as argument, e.g.

```
rosrun stage stageros `rospack find stage`/world/willow-erratic.world
```

Now you can receive on the /base_scan topic and publish to the /cmd_vel topic with your own program.

If you want to create your own world file, you need a position and laser model for your robot and a suitable floor plan (usually a bitmap) that encodes the obstacles. For the exact syntax, you can read the [manual](http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/doc/Stage-3.2.1/) or look at the existing world files.

---

Originally posted by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) with karma: 1951 on 2011-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-10-29**:
@Röhling : Nice command for stage, I was using ./stageros from the stage executables - but this is much better ! :-)

**Comment by [tonyParker](https://answers.ros.org/users/15131/tonyparker/) on 2014-09-11**:
Hi, I stage is not running on my machine , I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and Hydro, when I entered above command it shows this error:

[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named stageros below /opt/ros/hydro/share/stage

**Comment by [tonyParker](https://answers.ros.org/users/15131/tonyparker/) on 2014-09-19**:
ROS Hydro use stage 4.1.1. for this version try

rosrun stage_ros stageros ..............

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks! I managed to get inside it and now I'm trying to publish manually info into cmd_vel. I checked with rosmsg show what type it is and I get it's a vector:

```
alonsoj1@aut-228:~/ros_workspace$ rosmsg show geometry_msgs/Twist
geometry_msgs/Vector3 linear
  float64 x
  float64 y
  float64 z
geometry_msgs/Vector3 angular
  float64 x
  float64 y
  float64 z
```

I try the following ways:

```
alonsoj1@aut-228:~/ros_workspace$ rostopic pub /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist -- 2,3,1 0,0,0
ERROR: No key named [2,3,1]
Args are: [linear.x linear.y linear.z angular.x angular.y angular.z]
```

Then like this:

- 2.0 3.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
- 2 3 1 0 0 0
- [2 3 1] [0 0 0]

### But none of them work, any ideas?
Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [jlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1132/jlo/) with karma: 385 on 2011-10-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-10-14**:
The twist message doesn't specify any coordinates. It specifies linear and angular velocities. Information about the units used in ROS can be found here: http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html. Linear velocities are specified in m/sec and angular velocities in rad/sec.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2011-10-14**:
rostopic pub /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist '{linear: {x: 1, y: 0, z: 0}, angular: {x: 0, y: 0, z: 1.0}}' see also http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/YAMLCommandLine

**Comment by [jlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1132/jlo/) on 2011-10-14**:
Found it in YAML manual: rostopic pub /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist -r 1 '[1, 1, 0]' '[2, 0, 0]' Now... what type of coordinates are used for angle? Like here in the first case http://smerobot-tools.prospektiv.de/robotic/eng/robot_coordinates.html ? I can't seem to figure them out (angles, most of al

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
So... if I understood correctly, I could be able to move the robot everywhere without using the angular velocity parameter, right?
I have tried and I can't manage to get it right: I can move the robot left and right (as seen in the screenshot) with the following commands:

```
rostopic pub /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist -r 1 '[10, 0, 0]' '[0, 0, 0]'
```

and back to the inverted direction (right):

```
rostopic pub /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist -r 1 '[-10, 0, 0]' '[0, 0, 0]'
```

I tried playing with the rest of coordinates (using y or z, but they didn't produce any visible result). I also tried to use the angular velocity parameter by themselves, but I couldn't manage to make the robot move.

[image: image description]

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks :)!

---

Originally posted by [jlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1132/jlo/) with karma: 385 on 2011-10-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1132/jlo/) on 2011-10-17**:
[SOLVED] Reading teleop_base_keyboard.cpp I found out that the only coordinates that matter are X of linear and Z of angular speed. With that, I managed to move the robot. An example, to make it move in a circle: rostopic pub /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist -r 10000 '[10, 0, 0]' '[0, 0, 5]'

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would suggest a slight modification to [Röhling's](http://answers.ros.org/users/798/rohling/) approach.

You can locate willow-erratic.world file at /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/simulator_stage/stage/world. Modify that world file slightly, towards the end of the file add *ctrl "wander"* as shown;

```
# throw in a robot
erratic( pose [ -11.277 23.266 0 180.000 ] name "era" color "blue" ctrl "wander")
block( pose [ -13.924 25.020 0 180.000 ] color "red")
```

and now if you try the command

```
rosrun stage stageros `rospack find stage`/world/willow-erratic.world
```

you should see the erratic robot move around in a 'wander' mode - moving around randomly avoiding obstacles.

---

Originally posted by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) with karma: 1108 on 2011-10-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-10-29**:
@jlo : http://www.ros.org/wiki/stage/Tutorials/IntroductiontoStageControllers

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-10-17**:
@jlo : it is not a code - it is integrated into Stage - if you want the 'wander' code which has been integrated into it then download Stage (ver 3.2.2) (http://sourceforge.net/projects/playerstage/files/Stage/) and check out the file Stage-3.2.2-Source/examples/ctrl/wander.cc

**Comment by [jlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1132/jlo/) on 2011-10-17**:
Do you happen to know where the code for that 'wander' mode is? Where can it be read?